# css/selenium: visiblity of an element does not change

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

I have an element (text box), which has the following attribute:

```
style="visibility: hidden;" and style="visibility: visible;"
```

When this textbox is empty the visibility is `visible` and vice-verse for when the textbox contains some text.
Now, I have a test-case in selenium where I am trying to get the attribute value of this attribute.
I remove all the text from the textbox and then check the style attribute. 
The following wired thing is happening: 
1. When i run the test-case and the Firefox window running the test-case is in focus, then the style comes out fine (visible, after removing the text in the textbox)
2. But when that window is not in focus my test-case always fails as the style attribute still shows `'hidden'` even though i have removed the text from  the text box.

could someone please help with this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this it ll work

```
selenium.get_eval("element = this.browserbot.findElement('locator'); vis =window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue('visibility');")
```

Comment: thanks for the help...could you please explain what this command does? Also, what is the reason for the problem which I am facing? I had just described the problem but don't know the reason why it is happening?

Comment: 1) This will get the visibility of element i.e if element is visible it will return visible or else hidden. 2) May be cursor still present on the text box det could be the reason y ur getting it as hedden.